# Edit cells of column in sheet based on if there's duplicates of whats entered in another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to have all cells in Column A of Sheet1 communicate with all cells in Column B of Sheet2 to check if the exact text in any cell of Column B already exists. If it does exist, as soon as the duplicate text is entered in a cell, I would like that exact cell where the duplicate text was entered to change its text to "Already exits"
Is there a way to do this through Google AppScript with the onEdit function?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpzBZ.png

[image]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/18QXD.png]

Answer (score 0):

#### Already Exisits

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const names = ['Sheet0', 'Sheet1'];//Sheet names two check
  const idx = names.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if (~idx) {
    const rA1 = e.range.getA1Notation();
    const shts = names.map(name => e.source.getSheetByName(name));
    shts.filter(s => shts.indexOf(s) != idx).forEach(s => {
      if(s.getRange(rA1).getValue() == e.value ) {
        e.range.setValue("Already Exists");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Version 2:

#### Includes specified column for each sheet

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const names = ['Data Collected', 'Imports'];//Sheet names two check
  const col  = [1,3];
  const idx = names.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if (~idx && e.range.columnStart == col[idx]) {
    const rA1 = e.range.getA1Notation();
    const shts = names.map(name => e.source.getSheetByName(name));
    shts.filter(s => shts.indexOf(s) != idx).forEach(s => {
      if(s.getRange(rA1).getValue() == e.value ) {
        e.range.setValue("Already Exists");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

#### Check for Sheet1 A in Sheet 2 C

Not written as an onEdit triggered function

```
function checkForAinC() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs1 = [... new Set(sh1.getRange('A2:A' + sh1.getLastRow()).getValues().flat())];
  const vs2 = sh2.getRange('C2:C' + sh2.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  let o = vs1.map((e, i) => {
    let f = 0;
    let idx = -1;
    do {
      idx = vs2.indexOf(e, f)
      if (~idx) {
        sh2.getRange(idx + 2, 3).setValue("Already Exists");
        //SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        f = idx + 1;
      }
    } while (~idx);
  })
}
```

Comment: this works TY! Just one follow up question- if the columns that need to be checked for duplicates vary between Sheet0 and Sheet1 how would I check that. If Sheet0 data was in column A and Sheet1 data was in Column C how would the code be revised?

Comment: What are they for each sheet and what are your sheet names?

Comment: The first sheets name is "Data Collected" and the second sheets name is "Imports". Column A in the "Data Collected" sheet needs to be checked for duplicates and column C in the "Imports" sheet needs to be checked for duplicates

Comment: It seems as though now that the function is only checking for duplicate cells in the exact row. If "123" is entered in row 2 of the "Data Collected" sheet it will only check row 2 in the "Imports" sheet to see if "123" is entered to edit to 'Already Exists'. Also the const col =[1,3] line doesn't seem to work as I was only getting it to change to 'Already Exists' in column A of either sheet

Comment: I guess I misunderstand what you want.  Please give me some examples to work with.  Images would be nice.

Comment: sorry for not being specific- provided screenshots above of the 'Data Collected' sheet and the 'Imports' sheet. I'd like for all cells in the "Latest Revision" column (A) of the Data Collected sheet to to be compared to the "Latest Revision" column (C) of the Imports sheet and to have it marked as 'Already Exists' if any of the cells match the exact text in the other column

Comment: apologies for the link to images instead of just pictures, I don't have enough points to post direct images but these are just imgur links not google drive links

Comment: don't want to bother again but I've been trying to troubleshoot the issue of having the two columns A and C from the 'Data Collected' sheet and the 'Imports' sheet to check one another for duplicates with no luck. Provided above are the imgur links to the two sheets